# control random number with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, random

This is my intent,

1. Generate random number
2. Store in variable
3. Clear variable
4. Generate new number greater than previous
5. Store in variable

I understand

```
(Math.floor(Math.random()*100)+1)
```

For 1-100 but not sure how to accomplish what I want exactly.

Comment: Why do you always need a greater number? What if you first pick is `99`?

Comment: You need to provide some more details of what you want to achieve. last+=new will always be > last

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will generate a random number and then find the next random number it finds that is greater than it (or equal to it if it is greater than or equal to 99):

```
var num = Math.floor(Math.random()*100)+1;
alert(num); //current number
var newNum;
while((newNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*100)+1) < num && newNum < 100);
alert(newNum); //new number > num (or == num if num >= 99)
```

Answer (score 1):

use

```
var ran_val = 1;
// ... some code goes here
ran_val = (Math.floor(Math.random()*100) + ran_val)
```

if you have no upper limit on the random numbers,

```
ran_val = (Math.floor(Math.random()*(100-ran_val)) + ran_val)
```

otherwise.
   fwiw, the random numbers you emulate this way are no longer uniformly distributed.

Answer (score 1):

```
var numb1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*100)+1, //Generate random number
    numb2 = 0;

while (numb2<numb1) {
    numb2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*100)+2; // Generate new number greater than previous
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6jW4L/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a global variable and a function that handles the random number generation.

You can do something like this:

```
var num = 1;

function generaterandom(){
    num = Math.floor(Math.random()*100)+num;
}
```